# How to properly name java class?

Tags: java, android, naming-conventions

I have two Activity in android, which has respective view to add and edit.

1. Activity which add user information, I have named this class to AddUserInformation
2. Another Activity which edit user information, I have named EditUserInformation

As a class naming convention, class name should start with noun. In my case it seems like method name.

How to name properly these classes.So that other developer can easily identify class purpose?

Comment: Those shouldn't be classes, they should be methods. An `AddUserInformation` object doesn't make sense does it? Put it under a more general class such as `User` where you have methods to add and edit information.

Comment: If these classes really are necessary, you could name them `UserInformationAdder` or `UserInformationEditor`.

Comment: Unless these classes *contain* the information needed to add or to edit the user. Although even in that case the word "Information" is redundant and you should have a class `UserModification` (I doubt that there is much difference between the information needed to add or to edit a user)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really grokked the object oriented paradigm it seems. The natural OO design for this would be a `User` class with member variables representing the "information", e.g. firstname, lastname, etc. Getter and setter methods for the various "information" fields would be used to access and add/update a user's information. Something like this:

```
public class User {
    // these fields represent the user's information
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    // constructor
    public User() {
    }

    // getters are used for accessing information

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    // setters are used for updating information

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
}
```

You could use the `User` class to add and update information like this:

```
// create a user
User user = new User();

// add some information
user.setFirstname("John");
user.setLastname("Coltrane");

// update some information
user.setLastname("Trane");

// access the user's information:
System.out.println("Hello Mr. " + user.getLastname());
```

Answer (score 0):

This name denotes method name. User is class as per OOPs concept. As par naming rule class name is defined using Camel case. So UserInformationAdder and UserInformationEditor are proper name.

Answer (score 0):

You should create classes according to object itself, not for business logic level. I can assume you will need a class like `DeleteUserInfo` later.

Try this: a class named `UserInfo`, `addUserInfo` or `editUserInfo` is just the method name.